# TinyMCE and wiris plugin - after save and load the equation isn't displayed (shows missing image)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, tinymce

**System**

- Linux server
- PHP 7
- Bootstrap 3
- jquery 311
- tinymce 4.5.2-38

**My Situation**

I added the wiris tinymce plugin and inserted some equations to the editor.
After saving, I tried successfully to display the equation on the frontend of my website.
I'm using a self-programmed authoring system to display the inserted text.

**My Problem:**

If I want to edit the content of the textarea (with equation) I'm going to load the content back to the editor:

`<textarea class="form-control"> <?php if(isset($content["inhalt"])){echo html_entity_decode ($content["inhalt"], ENT_QUOTES , "UTF-8");} ?></textarea>`

The wiris parser runs, but the equation isn't displayed correct. Instead a broken image icon is shown.

When I double click on the icon, the equation editor launches and everything looks ok. After clicking "OK" the equation is shown correct.

**My question**

What can I do, to display the equation on page load correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue. Since version 4.0 WIRIS plugin uses base64 images. By default, TinyMCE converts base64 images to blob objects. In order to avoid this behaviour it is mandatory to declare into the TinyMCE init function the function "images_dataimg_filter". You can find more detais at https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#images_dataimg_filter